# Latex in Medical Sciences Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion

Why Latex codes are not working in Medical Sciences Stack Exchange?

No code is giving any output. Please look into this matter.

Answer (score 5):

Not all sites in the network have MathJax enabled. [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216607/295232) is a complete list, and Medical Sciences is not on the list. The answer also states

> ## Why doesn't [site X] support MathJax?
>
> MathJax increases page load times drastically, so it's only supported on sites that have demonstrated a serious need for it.

This is usually done on the site's own Meta (you're there right now) by providing quite a few posts which would benefit from this. There are [alternatives](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164286/295232) which might work in the meantime.

Comment: I've never seen a request for it before, and in fact I've never seen anyone post a non-trivial formula, so I doubt SE would agree that it would really benefit us.

Comment: I'd agree with Carey; it's likely that any somewhat medical-related question that uses that much math would be a better fit for Biology.SE, CrossValidated, or perhaps Bioinformatics or Chemistry.

Comment: A question was there about physics involved in ECG and I was trying to answer using Vectors(dipole) and Electric Potential. But the latex codes weren't working. So I thought of asking this question.